# Call function from one nodejs server to another nodejs server in the same server

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have **two nodejs(serve)** in the **same server** running at same time, I want to **call a function from one to another**,
they are running with forever, it is like running normally like `nodejs file.js`

**What can I do?**

**Things that I think I can do...**

1.- create a server side in each with udp, and client side in each? and call the function when it requires

2.- join two server in one file and run it...
but i don't want it

**My question is what can I do?, is there another option for this?, I want different options from mine...?**

Comment: Are those two scripts or two *servers*? Because, if they are real servers they already have a TCP/UDP that you can call. If they are just two scripts doing some stuff and you need to share functionality between them, make a node module with that shared functionality and include the module in both scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of them being on a single machine or not, I'd recommend Redis pub-sub for cross-process communication without any strict requirements.

You might also want to fork those off of one main process to establish some communication, but that's rather unusual if you want a practical solution.
https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html
Also described here as the default solution. [Communicating between two different processes in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213501/communicating-between-two-different-processes-in-node-js)

Redis pub-sub should be more future proof and harder to accidentally break for you.

https://gist.github.com/reu/5342276

Comment: PS. There might be other options both more and less advanced. I'm suggesting this from experience. This is just an opinion

Comment: I will use redis for my two server, is like sockets udp

Answer (score 1):

Use **process.fork/send**

If both processes are node, node core provides a simple, event-driven IPC mechanism. You will however have to make the one process the "master" meaning that it starts the other.

http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/all.html#all_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options

- event-based
- bi-directional
- efficient
- uses only OS resources
- in-memory

taken from: [Inter-process event emitter for Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17866864/inter-process-event-emitter-for-node-js)

Comment: this option isn't for me, undertand that I have to add the second server in the first and when run the first the second server is running like child