# EventEmitter event not received

Tags: node.js, events, eventemitter

I have 3 files

**a.js the shared EventEmitter module**

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');

const myEmitter = new EventEmitter();

module.exports = myEmitter;
```

**b.js the publisher**

```
const myEmitter = require('./a');

// Perform the registration steps

let user = 1;

setInterval(() => {
    myEmitter.emit('user-registered', user);    
    user++;
}, 1000);

// Pass the new user object as the message passed through by this event.
```

**c.js the subscriber**

```
const myEmitter = require('./a');

myEmitter.on('user-registered', (user) => {
  // Send an email or whatever.
  console.log(user);

});
```

When I run b.js or the publisher, the events are being published continuously but when I run c.js in a separate window, it immediately quits execution, how do I make this work with the subscriber actually listening to the publisher

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'a separate window'? Do you mean a different nodeJS process altogether? If this is the case then EventEmitter won't solve your problem as the EventEmitter events exist within a single node process. See this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17866864/inter-process-event-emitter-for-node-js) for a possible answer if I understood your question correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble you're having is that you're trying to publish events in one process, and listen for them in a separate process. The core Events API is not intended for this kind of interprocess communication.

Adjusting your example to work would best be done by changing **a.js** to:

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');
const publisher = require('./b');
const subscriber = require('./c');

const myEmitter = new EventEmitter();

module.exports = myEmitter;
```

And then run **a.js** alone. This will run both publisher and subscriber in the same process.